# what is a rails3 application builder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

As per rails usage:

```
$ rails new --help
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]        # Path to a application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--old-style-hash]         # Force using old style hash (:foo => 'bar') on Ruby >= 1.9
      [--skip-gemfile]           # Don't create a Gemfile
```

What does this "application builder" refer to, and how does it compare to an application template (-m option)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Descriptions in API Doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/AppBuilder.html)

> The application builder allows you to override elements of the
>   application generator without being forced to reverse the operations
>   of the default generator.

In a nutshell, you can define your default set of dependencies before creating a new rails app.

Check [this post](http://pivotallabs.com/users/mbarinek/blog/articles/1437-rails-3-application-builders) for more info.